# Trouble organizing data from a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I am a newbie in `python` and have been working on a project in which I have to organize data from a `.txt` file into a `dictionary` (The key value of the dictionary should be the person's full name whilst the other data is its value in dictionary form) the `dictionary` inside the `dictionary` has to include -

- `item`
- `location`
- `date of purchase`
- `remarks`
- `salespeople`

The `.txt` document looks like this:

```
Jimothy Donovan
Guitar
California
20.6.2018
The frame is broken
ENDREMARK
Hank Pym
Daniel Bennet
X
Isaac Newton
Hourglass
San Jose
12.8.2019
The hourglass is not accurate anymore
would like replacement
ENDREMARK
Daniel Bennet
Ethan Cole
X
```

The code is like this:

```
def process_data(file: TextIO) -> Dict:
    CustomerDataDict = {}
    lines = file.readline().strip()
    x = 0
    for line in file:
        key = lines[x].strip()
        CustomerDataDict[key[0]] = lines[x+1].strip()
        CustomerDataDict[key[1]] = lines[x+2].strip()
        CustomerDateDict[key[2]] = lines[x+3].strip()

        start = lines.index('ENDREMARK\n')
        list_remark = lines[3:start]
        full_remark = ''
        for n in list_remark:
            full_remark += n
        CustomerDataDict[key[3]] = full_remark

        end = lines.index('X\n')
        salesppl_list = lines[start + 1:end]
        salespeople = []
        for name in salesppl_list:
            following.append(name.strip())
       CustomerDataDict[key[4]] = salespeople

        x = end + 1

    return CustomerDataDict
```

The format of the `Dictionary` should be:

```
{username: 
    {'item':itemname, 
     'location':location, 
     'date-of-purchase': DATE, 
     'remarks':remarks, 
     'salespeople': {names of salespeople}
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterator on the text lines and advance through it based on your structure:

```
text = """Jimothy Donovan
Guitar
California
20.6.2018
The frame is broken
ENDREMARK
Hank Pym
Daniel Bennet
X
Isaac Newton
Hourglass
San Jose
12.8.2019
The hourglass is not accurate anymore
would like replacement
ENDREMARK
Daniel Bennet
Ethan Cole
X"""
```

...

```
lines = iter(text.split("\n"))    # create iterator (get data from the file)

customerData = dict()
while True:
    username = next(lines,None)
    if not username: break
    customerData[username]        = userData    = dict()
    userData["item"]              = next(lines)
    userData["location"]          = next(lines)
    userData["date-of-purchase"]  = next(lines)
    userData["remarks"]           = remarks     = list()
    userData["salespeople"]       = salespeople = set()
    while True:
        remark = next(lines)
        if remark == "ENDREMARK": break
        remarks.append(remark)
    while True:
        salesperson = next(lines)
        if salesperson == "X": break
        salespeople.add(salesperson)
```

This will produce the desired dictionary as long as the data meets the expected structure.

```
print(customerData)
    
{'Jimothy Donovan':
     {'item': 'Guitar',
      'location': 'California',
      'date-of-purchase': '20.6.2018',
      'remarks': ['The frame is broken'],
      'salespeople': {'Daniel Bennet', 'Hank Pym'}},
 'Isaac Newton':
     {'item': 'Hourglass',
      'location': 'San Jose',
      'date-of-purchase': '12.8.2019',
      'remarks': ['The hourglass is not accurate anymore', 'would like replacement'],
      'salespeople': {'Ethan Cole', 'Daniel Bennet'}}
}
```

[EDIT] alternate version without using break statements (not that bad after all):

```
customerData = dict()
username = next(lines,None)
while username is not None:
    customerData[username]        = userData    = dict()
    userData["item"]              = next(lines)
    userData["location"]          = next(lines)
    userData["date-of-purchase"]  = next(lines)
    userData["remarks"]           = remarks     = list()
    userData["salespeople"]       = salespeople = set()
    remark = next(lines) 
    while remark != "ENDREMARK":
        remarks.append(remark)
        remark = next(lines)
    salesperson = next(lines)
    while salesperson != "X":
        salespeople.add(salesperson)
        salesperson = next(lines)
    username = next(lines,None)
```

Comment: Yes but it makes the code more repetitive and unwieldy.  What you need to do is get the next value once outside the loop (e.g. `username = next(lines,None)` and again at the end of the loop.  Then your loop can be `while username is not None:`.  Same goes for the remarks and salespeople loops.